# Reg match to search for a particular string with delimiter in informatica

Tags: regex, unicode, regex-group, informatica, information-extraction

I have a requirement in informatica to check for a particular row is a number ,if yes then check for a string inside a colum,if present then extract it or use  the original value.

IIF(IS_NUMBER(ID),IIF(REG_MATCH(NAME,'[a-zA-Z0-9&]*/[a-zA-Z0-9 &]*',LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTR(NAME,1,INSTR(NAME,' ',1))))),ID)

Sample Data to be searched in a column name using reg_match

1)  ABC/DEF/003
2) XYZV/S&A/ABC/004 
3) CDE/004/007
4)   OLL.CA/VAU/1234
5)   RAB/SQ/ABC/009

Substing and instring logic is working fine,I am facing issue with reg_match.in the code given above ,I was only testing for examples like ABC/DEF records to match, but even that is not happening ,could you please help me with this( to handle all the test data mentioned ).

Regards ,
Karthik

Comment: can you elaborate your question. your requirement is to check if all characters from input is a number or not? is that the right understanding?

Comment: hi, i need to search the sample data ( example given above)  in a column using reg match and if present extratc it ,i used REG_MATCH(NAME,'(.*)([^A-Z0-9\/\.\_])'),its picking whatever string is there before the first space character, but i need to fetch data which has like / delimeter only

Comment: Tried using the Evaluate Expression in debug mode to verify the output of the REG_MATCH?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. you are speaking about space character but i don't see any space in the same data.  .* is going to fetch everything if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks , i got the solution ..'[A-Za-z0-9._&]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9._&]+)+ .*'